# The fast way to select with where cause

Tags: oracle

I have table about 10 million records  which have table structure like this

```
-------------------------------------------
 BARCODE      | PRICE | BRAND 
-------------------------------------------
1001001000111 | 1 USD | A
1001001000112 | 1 USD | B
1001001000113 | 1 USD | A
1001001000114 | 1 USD | B
1001001000115 | 1 USD | C
 . . .
```

I want to get the barcode value where brand is equal to B; this is my query.

```
SELECT BARCODE 
FROM myTable 
WHERE BRAND='B';
```

I spent a lot of time to wait for the result, so I try to change `Where` condition from `Where BRAND='B'` to `BRAND NOT IN ('A','B','C',..)`. It seem to be faster than the first query with amount of element `in ('A','B','C',..)` is small, but as soon as the amount of elements `in ('A','B','C','D',...)` is getting huge the query is getting slower.

What is the fastest way to get my data?

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: How many rows does your query return?  Based on the sample data, you'd be asking for 3.3 million rows since there are only 3 distinct `brand` values.  But I'm guessing `brand` is more selective in your actual data.  Is there an index on `brand`?

Comment: 10 million records is not enormous... I would rather say it is a table size I've  been used to see a lot

Comment: *I have huge table about 10 million records* Huh! That is **NOT HUGE** at all.

Comment: Is column BRAND a VARCHAR2 column? Do you use `WHERE BRAND=B;` (without quotes **'B'**)? Is the database Oracle or MySQL?

Comment: @JustinCave i have 10 - 20 brand, and i dose not create index in brand because myTable create by CREATE TABLE myTable AS SELECT...

Comment: @MarmiteBomber sorry about my mistake the BRANDS Column id varchar2.

Comment: Try issuing this the following command and then retry your query: `CREATE INDEX MyTable_Brand_Idx ON mytable( Brand );`

Comment: If you only have 10-20 `brand` values, then your query is returning between half a million and a million rows.  It's very unlikely that an index would be useful here, you'd almost certainly be better served doing a full scan of the table.  How are you measuring the time your query takes-- the time to return the first row or the time to return the last row?  Are you measuring the time required to fetch data via your application (which may grow linearly with the number of rows returned by the query)?  How big in GB is your table?  10 million rows isn't much but if you've got a `BLOB`...

Comment: by "fastest way to get my data", do you mean get ALL of the data, or just the first x rows?

Comment: I'm suggesting that an index is unlikely to be helpful given that you're asking for between 5 and 10% of the rows in the table.  Indexes are generally useful when you're asking for a small fraction of the rows in the table.

Comment: @JustinCave Thank you very much sir.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues to address.

> I have huge table about 10 million records

Just `10 million` rows makes you say the table is **huge**? What is the **size**? What are the column data types? I have a table with `5 billion rows` and I could select the rows that I want in seconds. How do you measure size by number of rows? When you talk about huge quantity in database, please make sure you mention the size of the data and not the number of rows. 10 million rows could be `500KB` or `1GB`.

Coming back to the requirement,

> I want to get the barcode value where brand is equal to B

Oracle optimizer is smart enough to decide whether to go for a **Full Table Scan** or use an **INDEX**. Having said that, you must **gather the statistics** up to date. Also, if you figure out the **cardinality estimates**, then you could actually decide to create an index.

Based on the limited information, my suggestion is create an index on the `BRAND` column.

```
CREATE INDEX barcd_indx ON mytable(BRAND);
```

> WHERE BRAND=B;

Why would you *not use* **single-quotation marks** around the string literal? You should enclose a string value within single quotes:

```
WHERE BRAND='B';
```

Comment: Thank your for suggestion, i will fix my question 1.) Huge table and 2.) Add single-quotation on where.

Comment: @AlexPoole I need a coffee break. My eyes are not that bad, but it's just that I missed it :-) Thanks, fixed.

Comment: @AlexPoole Based on the details provided by OP so far, I don't see a reason to think about BITMAP index ;-) If OP is practically fetching less than ~5% rows from the table based on the filter predicate, I would go with a B-Tree index. Do you think I understood what you said or am I sounding stupid? :-)

Answer (score 0):

If there is no index on Brand then you will end up doing a full table scan.

If there is an index on Brand, but a large fraction of the table is for brand B the query optimizer may decide that a full table scan is still the best method.

If there is an index on brand, and B is fairly selective representing a relatively small fraction of the table, but the optimizer is still choosing to do a full table scan, then your statistics may be stale and you should try gathering fresh stats on the table.

Answer (score 0):

Check first your hardware setup. Here I have a similar table as yours

```
 SQL> select count(*), count(distinct brand) from my10m;

  COUNT(*) COUNT(DISTINCTBRAND)
 ---------- --------------------
   10000000                   19

  SQL> select round(BYTES/(1024*1024)) MB from dba_segments where segment_name = 'MY10M';

          MB
  ----------
         296
```

Start SQL*Plus and check the time you need for the scan of the table

```
  SQL> set timi on;
  SQL> set autotrace traceonly
  SQL> set array 5000
  SQL> select * from  my10m;

  10000000 rows selected.

  Elapsed: 00:00:10.10

  Execution Plan
  ----------------------------------------------------------
  Plan hash value: 2382977685

  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Id  | Operation         | Name  | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |       |    10M|   316M| 10314   (1)| 00:02:04 |
  |   1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| MY10M |    10M|   316M| 10314   (1)| 00:02:04 |
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So, in my case it took 10 seconds to full scan the table.  This is a simple benchmark, so
query with filter condition should not be worst than this.
Run this benchmark and compare the elapsed time with your query.

Note also that I set  ARRAYSIZE to 5000 which reduces the network roundtrips and may speed up the query. You don't say how you access the
date, but very probably you may also increase the fetch size.

Note - the 10 seconds is on my desktop, on a production database   much better results are expected.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @Goldarrow let us know you full scan elapsed time - you don't say exactly what is "lot of time to wait for the result"

Comment: I spend time about 3 - 4 minute.

Comment: @Goldarrow this is not a good result. Is the size of your segment comparable with my test data (300 MB)? Please post also your Oracle version (select * from v$version)

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

Partition the table on basis of Brand column.
If there less records for say Brand A,C you can have those in one partition.
If there are more records for Brand B, you can have one partition for that particular brand.

**Option 2**

You can also consider creating bitmap index on column brand.